# Read the article in Lagrange multiplier.And also find the value of x,y,z with help given book.

Tags: real-analysis

According to the book "Sparse and Redundant Representations: From Theory to Applications in Signal and Image Processing" by Michael Elad, in the section of "Regularization" (p.4), or read the article in Lagrange multiplier 
try to solve the optimization problem with

```
        f(x,y)=3−(2x^2+y^2)

          g(x,y)=x+y=3,
```

and then obtain

∂L/∂x , ∂L/∂y , ∂L/∂λ

and the solution of x,y,z.

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Solve the question of help the given book with Lagrange multiplier and  the finally find the value of x,y and z.

Comment: You're not very likely to find anyone here who is willing to read some random text to figure out notation and solve your problem. If you can recast it in a way that asks a question independent of the text, and show some effort to solve the problem on your part, you are much more likely to get help (and to avoid having your question closed).

Comment: https://books.google.co.in/books/about/Sparse_and_Redundant_Representations.html?id=d5b6lJI9BvAC&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y                                                     Hint: Have a look about details "Regularization" I hope this link your help for solved the question.                    Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Given equation:
    f ( x , y )   =    3 +  ( 2x^2 + y^2 )
    g ( x , y )  =   x + y = 3 ,

Lagrange multiplier defined by

```
L( x , y , λ  ) = f( x , y ) - λ g(x,y)
```

where the λ term may be either added or subtracted. If f(x0, y0) is a maximum of f(x, y) for the original constrained problem, then there exists λ0 such that (x0, y0, λ0) is a stationary point for the Lagrange function (stationary points are those points where the partial derivatives of L are zero).

L(x) = 3−(2x^2+y^2) + λ(x+y-3);

With λ being the Lagrange multiplier for the constrain set .Taking a derivative of L(x) with respect to x ,we obtain the requirement

∂L(x)/∂x = 0
 -4x+ λ = 0                 .............( 1 )
∂L(x)/∂y = 0
-2y+λ = 0                    .............( 2 )
∂L(x)/∂λ = 0
x+y = 0                       .............( 3 )
Substrate the equation (1) & (2), we get 
-2x+y = 0                  ...............(4)
Again substrate the equation (3) & (4),we get
3x =3
x=1;
Putting the value of x in the equation (3),
We get 
1+ y = 3
y=2;
Again Putting the value of x and y in the equation (1) ,we get 
-4(1) + λ =0
λ = 4;
Answer :x=1; y=2 and λ=4